# Simplies way to get value from Class List to String List

Tags: java, performance, list, class

I try to get value for each `TestClass` object in List to new String List.

For example:

```
public class TestClass {

     private String testValue;

     // setter and getter
}
```

And now in different class I do it like that :

```
List<TestClass> testClassList = getTestClassList();

List<String> testStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

for( TestClass testClass : testClassList ) {
     testStringList.add(testClass.getTestValue());
}

return testStringList;
```

And I wonder is there any simplest way to do this?

Comment: No, you have to iterate on it. Your approach is fine.

Comment: Would be nice if you could do some sort of mapping from one list to another, the way you would in Perl or Python, but I don't think there is any compact idiom for this in Java

Comment: It will be in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

As [Maroun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430744/simplies-way-to-get-value-from-class-list-to-string-list/21430946#comment32332691_21430744) mentioned, without using 3rd-party libraries, the approach you've followed is the right way to go. You need to iterate through the list to populate the other.

But if you don't mind using a 3rd-party library then,

you can use Apache's [`CollectionUtils.collect()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#collect%28java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer%29) method, along with [`TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/TransformerUtils.html#invokerTransformer%28java.lang.String%29) method. An example code for that would look like this:

```
Collection<String> testValuesList = CollectionUtils.collect(testClassList, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getTestValue"));
```

---

And even Guava's [`Lists.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) can be used, though I've not tested it myself.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun - Because its not just between *Stock Java and Me* anymore ;)